# How to make TextView inside ViewPager scroll vertically

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I've got a ViewPager and a TextView inside it. When content of TextView is larger then it is visible on screen, there shall be possibility to scroll it vertically. But it does not do this automatically :(

Here is an xml for **TextView**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#338877"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

And here is an xml for **ViewPager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPonkSwiper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lbPonkFooter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbPonkFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an adapter:

```
public class PonkPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    private int             pagesCount  = -1;
    private List<Ponk>      data;
    private App             app;
    private MockPersistence db;
    private Activity        activity;
    private TextView        currentView;
    private LayoutInflater  inflater;

    public PonkPageAdapter(Activity activity, byte section) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.app = ((App) activity.getApplication());
        this.db = app.getPersistence();
        this.section = section;
        this.data = db.findPonksBySection(section); // new LinkedList<Ponk>();
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //
        this.pagesCount = db.countPonksInSection(section);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return pagesCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position)
    {
        TextView tv = getNewView();
        Ponk j = data.get(position);
        tv.setText(j.text);
        tv.setTag(j.id);
        setFontSizeInSP(tv, app.getFontSize());
        tv.setTag(position);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(tv, 0);

        return tv;
    }

    private TextView getNewView()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         TextView tv = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.Ponk, null);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        currentView = (TextView) object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view)
    {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((TextView) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == (TextView) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've shown a `RelativeLayout` with a `ViewPager` and `TextView` in it and a separaye layout file with a `TextView` but nowhere is there anything which shows that separate `TextView` is used inside the `ViewPager`.

Comment: check this out bro, see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617951/scrollable-textview-in-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `TextView` in a `ScrollView` like

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...
```

Comment: does not work - i think the problem is with event propagation