# Scrollable TextView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `TextView` inside a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager` and I want to make the text in the `TextView` scrollable. For some reason this doesn't work and the textview does not scroll.

This is what I've tried:

Code in fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_view, container, false);
   about = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileView_aboutContent_textView);
   about.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());  
   return view;

}
```

xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profileView_aboutContent_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/profileView_age_editText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileView_age_editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileView_profileName_textView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:text="@string/provisional_about_text"
    android:textColor="#0066CC" />
```

I know this works because I used it to make a tetxview scrollable which is in an activity not in a fragment within a ViewPager. When I tried the same in my fragment it doesn't work. 
I've also tried to apply setmovementmethod to the textview in onStart method within the fragment class but that did not work either. I also thought the textview there was a problem with the `TextView` id and it was returning null so I tried to set the `TextView` text with `setText()`; in the fragment to see if the class was getting the textview id and it actually worked so I don't know why the setmovementmethod doesn't work.

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The TextView was scrolling vertically because it was following the Pager View behavior which was to move horizontally from one fragment to the other so I had to tell the TextView in the Fragment class not to follow the parent behavior.

This is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_view, container, false);
     about = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileView_aboutContent_textView);
    about.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            about.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

     about.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());  
    return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a scrollview to textview in layout like this...

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testText"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the complete code it works fine with Viewpager..

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter class inside MainActivity

```
 private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new TestFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

TestFargment.java

```
 public class TestFragment extends Fragment
{
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.profileView_aboutContent_textView);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    return row;
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work in the fragment either, I had already tried it and it does work on an activity but not in my fragment. I don't know why nothing works in the fragment view.

Comment: I should work .can u show your activity code how your adding the fragment into it?

Comment: I have 3 fragments and I'm using a viewPagerAdapter so the user can swipe from one fragment to the other. The viewPagerAdapter instantiate the 3 fragments. Then from the activity I set up the view that holds the fragments like this:       
   private void setUpView(){     
  viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.profileView_viewPager);
 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
  viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
           }

Comment: see my updated answer. i have a sample code as per your requirement.

Comment: Yeah I had already done all of that already and it doesn't work, thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: ok, Try to create a sample app with the code i shared in answer and see what goes wrong.since i works perfect for me.

Comment: I solved the problem but I can't answer my own question because my reputation is too low. The TextView wasn't scrolling vertically because it was following the Pager View behavior which was to move horizontally from one fragment to the other so I had to tell the TextView in the Fragment class not to follow that behavior. I'll answer the question when i'm able to in a few hours.